# Go around a final method in subclass in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, final

I'm learning about inheritance at the moment and I'm a bit confused with the limitations that declaring a method final in the superclass apply to the subclasses. 
Say I have a superclass BankAccount with a withdrawal method, which requires a user password and amount to be withdrawn and sets the account balance to (balance - amount). I would want to declare that method final, so that other subclasses wouldn't potentially override it and allow the client to withdraw money without changing the account balance.

```
public final void withdraw(double amount, String pass) {
    if (checkPassword(pass) && getBalance() >= amount;) {
        setBalance(getBalance() - amount);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Rejected.");
    }
}
```

I want to avoid something like this from being allowed:

```
public void withdraw(double amount, String pass) {

}
```

However, some bank accounts allow overdrafts, which also have to be accounted for when making a withdrawal. Now, if I have a subclass BankAccountOverdraft, the inherited withdraw method is final so I won't be able to change any parts of it. But still, I MUST account for the overdraft limit in the subclass? How can I go about doing this?

```
    public void withdraw(double amount, String pass) {
    if (checkPassword(pass) && getOverDraftLimit() + getBalance() >= amount) {
        setBalance(getBalance() - amount);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Rejected.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You gave the answer yourself? Implement the method getOverDraftLimit in the superclass with a default value, and override it in the subclasses which specify a limit.

Comment: Why not simply add an `allowedOverdraft` attribute to `BankAccount` and neglect `BankAccountOverdraft`? A different solution would be to define a method `getAllowedOverdraft()` within `BankAccount` (as not final), which returns ``0``. You can overwrite this method within `BankAccountOverdraft` to return, what you want it to return and use it within `BankAccount`'s `withdraw(...)` method.

Comment: By the way, as a learning exercise this is fine, but in reality this kind of business constraint (with real money at stake) is probably never implemented through inheritance. You usually have explicit business rules.

Comment: Just don't declare your method final if it is not definitely final. Simply override it only where it is needed (in BankAccountOverdraft).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard But then the subclass may accidentally omit the password check or something.

Comment: But wouldn't implementing a `getOverDraftLimit` in `BankAccount` make having `BankAccountOverdraft` and using inheritance in general pointless? I don't want all subclasses of `BankAccount` to have overdraft...

Comment: @jack You need some "common ground" to start from. You cannot use some attributes/methods within a class without the class knowing about this attributes/methods (e.g. if only some sub-classes define this attributes/methods).

Comment: @jack It doesn't make inheritance pointless, it just makes it unsuitable for this task in the form you wrote your example.

Comment: You can define e.g. a subclass that makes `getOverDraftLimit` `final` with a value of 0 and then "limit" clients to just subclasses of that. It's not pointless but inheritance is at the same time not the right tool to enforce rules. See reflection.

Comment: Ok, that makes it a bit more clear, thank you for your help, guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you need to ask: is the withdraw procedure different for an account with overdraft? No, it isn't really, the process is the same: you check the password, you check there are enough funds, you debit the account.

What is different is the `check there are enough funds` step. So your abstraction should reflect this, as it does with  `checkPassword()`.

```
public final void withdraw(double amount, String pass) {
 if (checkPassword(pass) && checkFundsAvailable(amount)) {
    setBalance(getBalance() - amount);
 } else {
    System.out.println("Rejected.");
 }
}

protected boolean checkFundsAvailable(double amount) {
  return amount <= getBalance();
}
```

And when you can have overdraft, you override it with:

```
protected boolean checkFundsAvailable(double amount) {
  return amount <= getBalance() + overdraftLimit;
}
```

This way your superclass doesn't have to know about overdraft limits or anything really. You could implement a locked account as a subclass of it, which rejects all withdraw requests, or you can put any other logic into `checkFundsAvailable()`.

**P.s.:** Despite all the above, there is a very good reason not to approach this problem with inheritance (if it was a real problem and not just an exercise), but it's more subtle. By having a `BankAccount` class and a `BankAccountOverdraft` subclass, you also claim that **accounts that don't allow overdrafts can never be turned into overdrawable ones**, and vice versa. But real bank accounts don't behave like that, you can start with no overdraft allowed and agree an overdraft limit later. Inheritance has no way to express this, you'll need to use some form of composition.

Comment: Good explanation of some of the pitfalls of inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Others have suggested changing your design, but it's important to understand why your original design doesn't work.

Your `BankAccount` class behaves a certain way when you attempt to overdraft.  That behavior is part of its implicit API.  A class that allows overdrafts breaks that API by [weakening the postcondition](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/170142/145776) that the balance cannot be negative.  In a sense, it *is not* a `BankAccount`.  Therefore, it should not be a subclass of `BankAccount`.  Making the class or methods `final` is Java's way of enforcing this.

As biziclop notes, it is possible to use inheritance to express the relationship between an account that can overdraft and one that can't.  But making either one the parent of the other breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle.  Instead, make the two classes implement or extend a common interface or superclass that does not specify the overdraft behavior.  Perhaps the superclass should not include the `withdraw` method at all.  Avoid writing one class that works both ways.  If a client of your API has to test an object's behavior and capabilities, you've circumvented the strong typing that is one of Java's greatest strengths.

There's a great book called *Effective Java* that every Java programmer should read.  It talks about how [inheritance breaks encapsulation](http://igstan.ro/posts/2011-09-09-how-inheritance-violates-encapsulation.html) and how every class that allows inheritance must be designed very carefully.  For these reasons, I think it's a terrible disservice to students that inheritance is one of the first things taught in an introductory programming class.  It should be one of the last.

Comment: I fully agree with this, but it should be noted that in this case the postcondition doesn't have to be universal. If your model says the postcondition can be different for different accounts, then it is possible to express this through inheritance. I'd give a separate +1 for the comment on teaching if I could, 90% of the examples of inheritance I encountered in my education were invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your example is just to illustrate the design problem.  Normally you wouldn't protect a resource like a bank account with something as simple as a string comparison and an API restriction.  There are a number other issues like race conditions as well.

What you can do is split `withdraw` into two separate methods.  The `super` method can be marked `final`, and you can have a second `protected` method which isn't marked `final` that does the actual withdraw.  This forces the check to happen, but allows the actual withdraw behavior to be dynamic.

```
public final void withdraw(double amount, String pass) {

    if (checkPassword(pass)) {
        withdraw(amount);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Rejected.");
    }
}

protected void withdraw(double amount) {

  if (getBalance() >= amount) {
    setBalance(getBalance() - amount);
  } else {
    System.out.println("Rejected.");
  }
}
```

In a deriving class...

```
@Override
protected void withdraw(double amount) {

  if (getOverDraftLimit() + getBalance() >= amount) {
    setBalance(getBalance() - amount);
  } else {
    System.out.println("Rejected.");
  }
}
```

I should add that there are a number of different approaches to this problem, and the solution depends on overall the goals.  Inheritance is not always the correct way to add dynamic behavior.  One of the problems with the above is that it requires adding a new derived class to change withdraw behavior, which can lead to overly complicated class hierarchies.  Adding an overdraft amount to the class would allow the same, and avoid a lot of the added problems of inheritance.